# Dolbeault coholomogy induced by pull-back of forms

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Ive been racking my brain and I cant seem to get it right. I have proven that the pull back induces a linear map between the de rham cohomologies of groups but I still cant prove that a pull-back
$f* : C^\infty(Y, \Omega^k) \rightarrow C^\infty(X, \Omega^k)$
induces a linear map between the Dolbeault coholomogy 
$f* : H^{p,q}(Y) \rightarrow H^{p,q}(X)$ ?
And yes $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is holomorphic.
I think i need to show that pull back maps forms of type (p,q) to type (p,q) before I can show that the induced map is linear or well-defined.

Comment: $f$ should be holomorphic.

Comment: @MikeMiller yeah true it should be holomorphic. But im still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do need to know that, so see [this recent post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2452717/pull-backs-of-maps-forms-of-type-p-q-to-type-p-q). And then it will follow by type considerations that $\bar\partial$ commutes with pullback, so pullback by a holomorphic function respects the Dolbeault cohomology.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the De Rham cohomology, the pullback of a smooth map induces a linear map in cohomology since it commutes with the exterior derivative. For the Dolbeault cohomology, this is the exact same thing with $\overline{\partial}$ and holomorphic functions, namely:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be two complex manifolds and let $f\colon X\rightarrow Y$ be a holomorphic function, then one has:
>   $$\forall u\in C^\infty(X,\Lambda^{p,q}),f^*\overline{\partial}u=\overline{\partial}f^*u.$$